# is it possible to copy child nodes into output XML without namespaces?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to copy all the child elements of soap:Header element and soap:Body element into a new element outputWithoutNS, while doing that I am seeing namespaces in the output XML, is it possible to copy child nodes into output XML without namespaces?

INPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap ="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header xmlns="http://www.ama.net/1axml-msg/schema/msg-header-1_0.xsd">
  <MessageHeader ResponseRequested="true" version="1.0" Terminate="true" Reverse="true" id="09B5581A" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
    <From>1ASI</From>
    <To>1ASRINSAIG</To>
    <TimeStamp>
      <GenerationTime>2014-10-22T12:41:38Z</GenerationTime>
    </TimeStamp>    
  </MessageHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<PricingRequest xmlns="http://www.ama.net">
    <originatorSection>
        <deliverySystem>
            <companyId>1A</companyId>
            <cityCode>MUC</cityCode>
        </deliverySystem>       
    </originatorSection>    
</PricingRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i am trying below XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.ama.net" xmlns:foo="http://www.ama.net/1axml-msg/schema/msg-header-1_0.xsd"xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" exclude-result-prefixes="soap x foo">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="SOAPHeader" select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/node()" />       
        <xsl:variable name="PricingRequest" select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/node()" />         
        <xsl:element name="outputWithoutNS">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$SOAPHeader"/> 
            <xsl:copy-of select="$PricingRequest"/> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT XML getting (namespaces at MessageHeader and PricingRequest):

```
<outputWithoutNS>
  <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ama.net/1axml-msg/schema/msg-header-1_0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ResponseRequested="true" version="1.0" Terminate="true" Reverse="true" id="09B5581A" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
    <From>1ASI</From>
    <To>1ASRINSAIG</To>
    <TimeStamp>
      <GenerationTime>2014-10-22T12:41:38Z</GenerationTime>
    </TimeStamp>
  </MessageHeader>
  <PricingRequest xmlns="http://www.ama.net" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <originatorSection>
      <deliverySystem>
        <companyId>1A</companyId>
        <cityCode>MUC</cityCode>
      </deliverySystem>
    </originatorSection>
  </PricingRequest>
</outputWithoutNS>
```

Expecting OUTPUT (no namespaces at MessageHeader and Pricing Request):

```
<outputWithoutNS>
  <MessageHeader ResponseRequested="true" version="1.0" Terminate="true" Reverse="true" id="09B5581A" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
    <From>1ASI</From>
    <To>1ASRINSAIG</To>
    <TimeStamp>
      <GenerationTime>2014-10-22T12:41:38Z</GenerationTime>
    </TimeStamp>
  </MessageHeader>
  <PricingRequest>
    <originatorSection>
      <deliverySystem>
        <companyId>1A</companyId>
        <cityCode>MUC</cityCode>
      </deliverySystem>
    </originatorSection>
  </PricingRequest>
</outputWithoutNS>
```

Comment: There is one problem, what do you want to do with the `soap:mustUnderstand="1"` attribute, if you want to have it preserved in the output then the output will keep the soap namespace declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write templates to strip the namespaces and apply those templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.ama.net/1axml-msg/schema/msg-header-1_0.xsd"
  xmlns:ns2="http://www.ama.net" ... exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 ns2">

<xsl:template match="ns1:* | ns2:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">     
    <outputWithoutNS>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/node() | /soap:Envelope/soap:Body/node()"/> 
    </outputWithoutNS>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi martin, it works like a charm. perfect. thanks for your quick response